# Help with generating functions

Tags: recurrence-relations, power-series, generating-functions

I've got two questions. 
 
I'm trying to extract the "coefficients" of a power series. I think my terminology is incorrect here but here is what I mean.


Here are some examples

- A(Z) = 1/(1-Z)            a(n) = 1;
- A(Z) = 1/(1-Z)^2,      a(n) = (n + 1)
- A(Z) = 1/(1-z)^3        a(n) = (1/2)(n+1)(n+2)

But how do I express something like this in terms of a(n) (i need it to solve recurrence relatoins).

- A(Z) = 5*Z            a(n) = ??
- A(Z) = 5               a(n) = ??

The last term is just a constant (I used 5 as an example) and the second last time is a constant multiplied by Z. 

Any help would be most appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{(1 - z)^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{d}{dz^{n}}\left(\frac{1}{1 - z}\right)\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A(z)=5z$, then $$a(n)=\begin{cases}5,&\text{if }n=1\\0,&\text{otherwise}\;.\end{cases}$$ If $A(z)=5$, change the first case to $n=0$ instead of $n=1$.

If you know about [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), you can write the first more simply as $a(n)=5[n=1]$ and the second as $5[n=0]$.

Comment: Thank you How about A(Z) = 1/(Z-1) ?

Comment: @fatffatable: That’s just $-\frac1{1-z}$, so ... ?

Comment: If its not too much trouble, how about A(Z) = 1/(3z-1)^2 ?

Comment: @fatffatable: You know that $$\frac1{(1-u)^2}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)u^n\;.$$ Let $u=3z$, so that the coefficient of $z^n$ is $3^n(n+1)$, and then note that you want the negative of this function.

Comment: @fatffatable: I can’t stay too long: I was just about to go fix dinner.